# How to load initial data to a form in Django?

Tags: django, deployment, django-forms, backend

I need to load data from database to form, so user can update it, but can't find a way to do it. With the method below I get `<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x000001DB8861EAC0>` instead of currency. How to get data before putting it to dictionary in `init_supplier`?

Here is my `view.py`:

```
def supplier_form(request):
    s_data = supplier.objects.all 
    init_supplier = {
        'currency' : supplier.currency
    }
    submitted = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = s_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home?submitted=TRUE')
    else:
        sup_form = s_form(initial=init_supplier)
        if submitted in request.GET:
            submitted = True
    return render(request, 'forms/supplier_form.html', {'sup_form':sup_form, 'submitted':submitted, 's_data' : s_data})
```

Here is my `Models.py`:

```
class Supplier(models.Model): 
    company_name = models.OneToOneField(User, max_length=120, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING) 
    currency = models.CharField('Currency', max_length=4)
    legal_form = models.CharField('Legal form', max_length=100, choices=legal_form_options, default='Sole proprietorship')
    accounting_standards = models.CharField('Accounting standards', max_length=100) 
    owner_structure = models.CharField('Owner structure', max_length=100) 
    industry_sector = models.CharField('Industry sector', max_length=100, choices=industry_sector_options, default='Advertising')
```

So far tried with `__init__` in forms and filtering in views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `s_data = supplier.objects.all` into `s_data = supplier.objects.all()` - it's a method, not an attribute. Moreover, it will simply not work since you ask for `all()` not single supplier. You may need to do `suplier.objects.get(pk=XX)`. To test if this works, try: `s_data = supplier.objects.first()` - this will allow you to edit first supplier.
It is also important to use `initial` for POST request, otherwise it will create a copy of initial model, not update the existing one.

Reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values

Comment: Thanks for reply. I was trying to do it without IDs, because I can't get IDs from db, but all the solutions use IDs. So I've got `href="{% url 'supplier_data' supplier.id %}"` in html, `def supplier_data(request, supplier_id): 
        s_data = Supplier.objects.filter(id=supplier_id)
        return render(request, 'forms/supplier_data.html', {'s_data' : s_data})` in views, `path('supplier_data/<int:supplier_id>', views.supplier_data, name="supplier_data"),` in urls and get no result. No id for objects.filter and objects.get.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in python, A class name always start with an Uppercase or a PascalCase. You can read more about it [Here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).
As per your problem, you can try this

```
def supplier_form(request, pk):
    s_data = get_object_or_404(Supplier, id=pk)
    init_supplier = {
        'currency' : s_data.currency
    }
    #Then your custom logic should follow
    return render(request, 'forms/supplier_form.html', {'sup_form':sup_form, 'submitted':submitted, 's_data' : s_data})
```